# HTML to PDF in JS using a variable

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

This is my first post because I am stuck and I didn't find the solution neither here or the web.

I want to convert HTML to PDF using JS. I was searching and the best option seems to be HTML2canvas and JSpdf. But the think is my HTML is storage in a variable:

```
var test = '<html><head><script type="text/javscript">var number = 123;</script></head><body>
<h1>"the value for number is: " + number</h1></body></html>'
```

My variable is much more complex and it contains CSS and styles but this is just to get the idea. Then when I try to convert this into canvas it doesn't convert.

```
const filename  = 'ThisIsYourPDFFilename.pdf';

html2canvas(test).then(canvas => {
    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
    pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 211, 298);
    pdf.save(filename);
});
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Maybe it is a really stupid question but I don't know how to avoid the errors.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to convert html code of the page or some html stored in some variable?

Comment: html stored in a variable to pdf

Comment: I have updated my response, it might be something you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You use string as a parameter for html2canvas, but it takes HTML element:

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

[Look at their documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas)

I have modified your code:

```
const html2canvas = require("html2canvas");
const jsPDF = require("jspdf");

html2canvas(document.getElementById("screenshot"), { scale: 1 }).then(
  (canvas) => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    const filename = "ThisIsYourPDFFilename.pdf";
    let pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
    pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), "PNG", 0, 0);
    pdf.save(filename);
    document.body.removeChild(canvas);
  }
);
```

body should contain element with id screenshot:

```
<div id="screenshot">
    Content
</div>
```

**UPDATE**:

According to [this resource](https://www.codexworld.com/convert-html-to-pdf-using-javascript-jspdf/) jsPDF has method `fromHTML`, so you might not need html2canvas

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var elementHTML = $('#contnet').html();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#elementH': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
// note here that it uses html
doc.fromHTML(elementHTML, 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});

// Save the PDF
doc.save('sample-document.pdf');
```

Comment: I was trying the fromHTML and it didn´t work neither in my example. I am able to print something but not the HTML it self. I think it is because I use css files in head.

Comment: Imagine that I have a invoice stored in a variable in HTML and i want to convert it into pdf

Comment: May be https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-pdfmake would help you?